# Would stating that $(-\infty, +\infty)= \mathbb{R}$ be correct?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I am working on a task given by my teacher. At some point, I want to state that $(-\infty, +\infty)= \mathbb{R}$. Would this be mathematically correct?

I am sorry if that is a dumb question, I am just really unsure, as in math there are often small notational particularities that are counter-intuitive.

Comment: As a set equality, I think they are equal (they are surely equivalent because you can construct a bijection between the two).

Comment: @OsamaGhani ability to construct a bijection is not enough, since stuff like $(0,1)$ also has a bijection to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I agree. I meant bijection implies equivalence, and since the sets have the same elements and the same 'amount', they're equal.

Comment: @OsamaGhani: you've repeated the mistake when you say "bijection implies equivalence." That's not true if by "equivalence" you met "set equivalent." (The relation of "there exists a bijection between" *does* define an equivalence relation between sets -- if you allow yourself to speak of the class of all sets -- but that's not what's at issue here.) As Alice pointed out, there is a bijection between the interval $(0,1)$ and the set $\mathbb{R}$, but those sets are not equal. The converse is true, tho: if two sets are equal, then there exists a bijection between them (in fact, the identity).

Comment: @symplectomorphic I was going off of definitions here http://wizznotes.com/mathematics/sets/equal-and-equivalent-sets and http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/equal-sets.html

Comment: The usage of symbols $\pm\infty$ as end point of intervals is pretty standard and by definition your equality holds. In the same manner we have definitions like $(a, \infty) =\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}, x>a\} $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah it is correct.

The first notation means all real numbers larger than $-\infty$ and less than $+\infty$, and the second notation means all real numbers, but since any real number is larger than $-\infty$ and less than $+\infty$, it excludes no real numbers.